# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Identity. How to get current ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, identity, asp.net-identity

I have an Article entity in my project which has the `ApplicationUser` property named `Author`. How can I get the full object of currently logged `ApplicationUser`? While creating a new article, I have to set the `Author` property in `Article` to the current `ApplicationUser`.

In the old Membership mechanism it was simple, but in the new Identity approach I don't know how to do this.

I tried to do it this way:

- Add using statement for Identity extensions: `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;`
- Then I try to get the current user: `ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == User.Identity.GetUserId());`

But I get the following exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
>     Source=EntityFramework

Answer (score 473, accepted):

### You should not need to query the database directly for the current ApplicationUser.

That introduces a new dependency of having an extra context for starters, but going forward the user database tables change (3 times in the past 2 years) but the API is consistent. For example the `users` table is now called `AspNetUsers` in Identity Framework, and the names of several primary key fields kept changing, so the code in several answers will no longer work *as-is*.

Another problem is that the underlying OWIN access to the database will use a separate context, so changes from separate SQL access can produce invalid results (e.g. not seeing changes made to the database). Again the solution is to *work with* the supplied API and not try to *work-around* it.

The correct way to access the current user object in ASP.Net identity (as at this date) is:

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

or, if you have an async action, something like:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

`FindById` requires you have the following using statement so that the non-async `UserManager` methods are available (they are *extension methods* for UserManager, so if you do not include this you will only see `FindByIdAsync`):

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

If you are not in a controller at all (e.g. you are using IOC injection), then the user id is retrieved in full from:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

If you are not in the standard Account controller you will need to add the following (as an example) to your controller:

### 1. Add these two properties:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Application DB context
    /// </summary>
    protected ApplicationDbContext ApplicationDbContext { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// User manager - attached to application DB context
    /// </summary>
    protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; set; }
```

### 2. Add this in the Controller's constructor:

```
    this.ApplicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
    this.UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(this.ApplicationDbContext));
```

**Update March 2015**

Note: *The most recent update to Identity framework changes one of the underlying classes used for authentication.* You can now access it from the Owin Context of the current HttpContent.

```
ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

### Addendum:

When using EF and Identity Framework with Azure, over a remote database connection (e.g. local host testing to Azure database), you can randomly hit the dreaded “error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable”. As the cause is buried away inside Identity Framework, where you cannot add retries (or what appears to be a missing `.Include(x->someTable)`), you need to implement a custom `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy` in your project.

Comment: @TBA - thanks, I realized later it's an extension method. Need to add Microsoft.AspNet.Identity using . thanks again

Comment: Type or namesapce UserStore could not be found.I added using Microsft.AspNet.Indentity

Comment: Why You should not need to query the database directly for the current ApplicationUser?

Comment: Isn't the ApplicationUser stored in the current context ?

Comment: Doesn't work for me.
var user = UserManager.FindById(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId());

Error 1 Using the generic type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<TUser>' requires 1 type argumens.
Lookin at the metadata it doesn't even have this method, and the class isn't static.

Comment: Found the solution and posted it here in a comment:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483227/asp-net-identity-how-to-get-current-identityuser-applicationuser-where-is-us

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I had the using statement, but still I had this error. The problem was I was trying to use it outside the controller, From a hub of SignalR, so I had to initialize evertyhing before the call, like that:
`ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(); UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(applicationDbContext));
var user = userManager.FindById<ApplicationUser> Context.User.Identity.GetUserId());`

Comment: Just to mention, I saw this code is very time consuming, I will try to use it only once, or try to put it in static properties.

Comment: From what I saw the initialization of it is slow, I don't care if the UserManager is shared between users. It's not different anyhow. I wouldn't want to initialize it for each request. Strange there is no method to get the user object from the context, it only gives you Id or UserName.

Comment: @Ronen Festinger: Sorry, I just saw your *first* comment and now see what you are talking about. Yes *that part* can be made static.

Comment: The previous comment has some issues with child custom objects not loading for the ApplicationUser. This is a better code:
`private static ApplicationUserManager _userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(); var user = _userManager.FindByName<ApplicationUser, string>(userName);`

Comment: Actually, static doesn't work well, because it's not updated, you should use: `private ApplicationUserManager _userManager { get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(); } }`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie : Do you mean the User's Id in the User table by "GetUserId()"? I mean that for example there is a User table wit ID and UserName columns. When calling SaveChanges() method,  I want to use ID rather than UserName in order to add this ID to my Audit / Logging tables. How can I do this?

Comment: @H.Johnson. Please ask a new question, not via comments. The API means you should not have to hit the database directly for saving changes either.

Comment: Is there no way to extend the @User.Identity. class and add other values there? For example I want to get a value from the user, its displayed on every page? Do i really have to do another db access? Surely its already accessing the db somewhere to get the ID and the username?

Comment: @Zapnologica: That sounds like a new question (suggest you post it). You can extend the `ApplicationUser` class (application specific) and the `AspNetUsers` table in parallel and they will provide any new fields. Again: Do not hit the database directly! :)

Comment: Yes but by overriding the application user, doesn't mean that those fields will always be accesaible from the httpcontext like `User.Identity.UserName` is.

Comment: @Zapnologica: The Identity is a different animal to the application user. `ApplicationUser` uses `Identity.UserName`, but any extension data is in the `ApplicationUser` (by way of the AspNetUsers table). Either you should work *with* `ApplicationUser` or expect maintenance troubles if you hit the database directly. You have been advised :)

Comment: I have `ApplicationUser:IdentityUser` with some of my own properties. How do I get that without accessing db? Your answer is only giving me access to `IdentityUser` stuff

Comment: @LifeH2O: The ApplicationUser returned by FindById is *your* class, complete with *your* extra properties. Please try it.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I am amazed that this isn't the accepted answer, too often the quick fix is the accepted and best practice answer is not.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Oh, didn't spot that. :)

Comment: Waiting For your new Workaround :P

Comment: Do you have a new work around as promised at the end of your answer?

Comment: @Reafidy: Yeah, sorry about that. The Owin context on the current HttpContext exposes it now, so I have added an alternative.

Comment: Does HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager>().FindById(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()) hit the database or not?

Comment: @Aleksa: The `GetUserId()` method *may* hit the database, or it may be cached, but you should not care as that implementation detail is hidden (and it is very fast anyway). Why do you ask?

Comment: I asked for GetUserManager<UserManager>().FindById method, because I want to be sure it gets the newest data for User, not something cached.

Comment: @Aleksa: it depends on how the database is modified. If you use a different context to update the database the UserManager will not return the updates. This is why you should only go through the API.

Answer (score 65):

My mistake, I shouldn't have used a method inside a LINQ query.

Correct code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;


string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
```

Comment: User.Identiy.GetUserId does not exist for me. is that i custom method? I only get up to User.Identity

Comment: Nevermind... you need the "using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;" for that method to be there.

Comment: Just a note, the User object is visible only in Controllers.

Comment: Surely you should be using `UserManager` methods and not hitting the database directly?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Could you elaborate a bit on the difference? Both methods would pull data from the database wouldn't they?

Comment: @Josh Bjelovuk: Never hit a database directly when an API is available. That introduces a new dependency of having an extra context for starters, but going forward the user database tables change (3 times in the past 2 years) but the API is consistent.

Comment: @Ellbar I think you should consider changing the accepted answer to Gone Coding's. As you can see, his approach uses the relevant ASP.NET Identity APIs instead of bypassing them and loading directly from the database as you do here.

Comment: var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();

Answer (score 33):

Its in the comments of the answers but nobody has posted this as the actual solution.

You just need to add a using statement at the top:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

Comment: I came here with that exception, I solved it with that `using`. Seeing as 15k people have visited the question I figured it was a helpful answer :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, despite not being a direct answer to the OPs question, I feel that mentioning the using is a very useful addition.

Comment: For clarity, it's because `.GetUserId()` is an extension method

Answer (score 11):

The code of Ellbar works! You need only add using.

1 - `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;`

And... the code of Ellbar:

2 - `string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);`

With this code (in `currentUser`), you work the general data of the connected user, if you want extra data... see [this link](http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customize-users-profile-in-aspnet.html)

Comment: It may "work", but it is certainly not *recommended* to bypass the supplied API and hit the database directly If you did use the API you would not need extra work to get the extra data *as it would already be in the `ApplicationUser` object*

Comment: I agree! However, resorted to this way because I had already have a system in place today, with a run in the database and I need a simple solution to solve this issue! Certainly, in an early system, I would put objects in their proper classes and identities.

Answer (score 6):

As of ASP.NET Identity 3.0.0, This has been refactored into

```
//returns the userid claim value if present, otherwise returns null
User.GetUserId();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
ApplicationUser currentUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

string ID = currentUser.Id;
string Email = currentUser.Email;
string Username = currentUser.UserName;
```

Answer (score 3):

Right now the asp.mvc project template creates an account controller that gets the usermanager this way:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
```

The following works for me:

```
ApplicationUser user = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Answer (score 3):

For MVC 5 just look inside the EnableTwoFactorAuthentication method of ManageController in WebApplication template scaffold, its being done there:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> EnableTwoFactorAuthentication()
        {
            await UserManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), true);
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
        }
```

The answer is right there as suggested by Microsoft itself:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

It will have all the additional properties you defined in ApplicationUser class.

Comment: Already covered. Please check that an identical answer is not already posted (or add a comment to an existing answer) :)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is working with `Identity` users in `web forms`, I got it working by doing so:

```
var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way :

```
User.Identity.Name
```

It provides the Id of the current user.

Answer (score -1):

I was successfully available to get Application User By Following Piece of Code

```
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            ApplicationUser EmpUser = user;
```