# Get current user id in ASP.NET Identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I just switched over to using the new 2.0 version of the Identity Framework.  In 1.0 I could get a user object by using `manager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId())`.  The `GetUserId()` method does not seem to exists in 2.0.

Now all I can figure out is to use `manager.FindByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name)` which references the username field in the users table.  In my application this is set to the same as the email field.

I can see this causing issues down the road when someone needs to update their email. Is there a way to get the current logged in user object based off an unchanging value *(such as the id field)* in the Identity 2.0 Framework?

Comment: How did you get the UserId, can you please let me know, I am running into a same issue.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

`GetUserId()` is an extension method on `IIdentity` and it is in `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions`. Make sure you have added the namespace with `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;`.

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925822/asp-mvc5-identity-how-to-get-current-applicationuser

Comment: That seems to be not working with Identity 2. Any suggestion please

Comment: Should still be there. I'm using GetUserId() in my Identity 2 projects right now.

Comment: In Identity 3.0 this looks to have moved to the System.Security.Principal namespace.

Comment: Is there any method to get current user role? when I should set the role? Note: I am using custom storage provider ..

Comment: Okay, as of beta4 it looks like it’s now in System.Security.Claims and applies to a ClaimsPrincipal instead of an identity

Comment: Why is this answer marked as the right one? The question is "where is GetUserId in ASP.NET Core?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765214/get-user-id-in-asp-net-core-2

Answer (score 64):

In order to get CurrentUserId in Asp.net Identity 2.0, at first import `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`:

**C#:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

**VB.NET:**

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
```

And then call `User.Identity.GetUserId()` everywhere you want:

```
strCurrentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

This method returns current user id as defined datatype for userid in database (the default is `String`).

Comment: could you tell me where can I found the corresponding DLL for Microsoft.AspNet.Identity namespace?

Answer (score 17):

Just in case you are like me and the Id Field of the User Entity is an Int or something else other than a string,

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

int userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
```

will do the trick

Answer (score 7):

I used Claims to get the userId, username and email of the logged in user.

```
            var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); // will give the user's userId
        //userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name); // will give the user's userName
        //email = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I am currently using Asp.net Core 2.2. I solved this problem with the following piece of code.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);
```

I hope this will be useful to someone.

Comment: This creates a superfluous DB call