# Get UserId in MVC to use in View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following problem in my MVC 5 web app. I used database first approach and the entity framwork to create a table `[accountlist]` that has a foreign key relationship on `[UserId]` to the `[Id]` column from `[AspNetUsers]`. Right now the pertaining `accountlist.cshtml` contains a dropdown menu. I also tried `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId, new { @Value = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name})` but the problem is how that I need the correct userid and not the username (I don't want the `[UserName]` from `[AspNetUsers]` to be an primary key).

Unfortunately, `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()` as suggested in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448637/how-to-get-current-user-and-how-to-use-user-class-in-mvc5) says that Identity contains no definition for GetUserId().

Does anyone has solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about this: `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.GetUserId()`?

Comment: `GetUserId` is an extension method... you might need to import the corresponding namespace.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624470/get-current-user-id-in-asp-net-identity-2-0)

Answer (score 5):

@stephen.vakil is correct. You need to import the namespace. Specifically, you need to add:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model Namespace.To.Foo
```

Alternatively, if you want to do this more often or just don't want to include the namespace in the view, you can edit the `Web.config` in the `Views` folder of your project and add it there instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    ...
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
```

Any namespaces there are available to every view automatically.

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiboqz99ozPAhXBl5QKHYD2D2QQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbenfoster.io%2Fblog%2Faspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1&usg=AFQjCNFRZEXnxqQfpHpXJuwS2WmqlxNiKg&sig2=iZkd0JmSQjdnBmaGhtQAMw) is the best Article for asp.net mvc authentication from ben foster. It helped me last time.

It works even if you are not going for entity framework

SigIn Like this

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, userID)
            },    
            "ApplicationCookie");

        var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
        var authManager = ctx.Authentication;

        authManager.SignIn(identity);
```

Create New Class

```
public class AppUser : ClaimsPrincipal
{
    public AppUser(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        : base(principal)
    {
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Sid).Value;
        }
    }   
}
```

Let's create a custom base view page for our Razor views that provides access to our AppUser principal:

```
public abstract class AppViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    protected AppUser CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            return new AppUser(this.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
        }
    }
}

public abstract class AppViewPage : AppViewPage<dynamic>
{
}
```

Open up /views/web.config and the set the pageBaseType:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="NakedIdentity.Mvc.AppViewPage">
```

Rebuild the project and update the Index.cshtml view:

```
<p>
  User ID: @CurrentUser.ID?
</p>
```

Comment: @Pang sure, I thought it would take some space to make my points clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SimpleMemberShip provider, then

```
int UserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
```

and add attribute [InitializeSimpleMembership] on the top of controller method.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your controller constructor:

```
user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

then you will have `user.Id` in all you methods inside your controller. And for security purpose, never keep your user id inside view as hidden!.