# Get user id in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to get the user id in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC project.

However, I was only able to get the email. I'm almost sure there has to be a 1/2 line way to get it (in the ASP.NET MVC membership it was just var loggedInUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

I tried so far like this:

```
 var loggedInUserId = User.Identity.ToString();    // Result = Name (E-mail) 
 //  var loggedInUserId = User.Identity.Name;    // Result (E-mail)
```

& this is now what I need

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The old method of `User.Identity.GetUserId()` no longer exists, but the id is available as a claim on your principal, i.e. `User`. There's a number of ways you can get to it:

1. The first and easiest is just pull out the claim:

   ```
   var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
   ```
2. If you already have an instance of `UserManager<TUser>` (or want to inject one), then you can use the `GetUserId()` method on that:

   ```
   var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
   ```
3. Finally, if you want the old way back, it's as simple as adding an extension to `ClaimsPrincipal` and utilize the first method above:

   ```
   public static class ClaimsPrincipalExtensions
   {
       public static string GetUserId(this ClaimsPrincipal principal) =>
           principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
   }
   ```

Comment: var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

this is giving null UserId value

Comment: Then the user either isn't logged in or there is no user (external login only, with no user creation).

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject dependency in the controller like shown below:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController: Controller
{
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager) 
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

Now, you can use below code anywhere inside that controller to get user details.

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.EmailID);
```

Now, You can use user.Id to get userId.

Comment: Thanks, The name '_userManager' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio for more details.

Comment: @AssafOur Is it useful?

Comment: thanks sorry it didn't (value =System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity ) what it the model (model.EmailID) stand for ?

Comment: You need to pass email id there.

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.net Core 2.2, I solved this problem with the following piece of code.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);
```

This way you will get the user information by his email. `User.Identity.Name` will provide you the email address of the current logged in user.

I hope this will be useful to someone.