# How can i find the current user id logged in .Net Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get the current user id logged in so I can pull details down for this user as well assign details to the user e.g. booking events, seeing events they have booked, etc.

I have been trying to do like this

```
var USERID = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Id")
```

but I get an error when trying to assign to int.

I have my service method within my data project connecting to db then I pass these methods from the service into the controller, if that helps at all.

Any help would be great.

Comment: "I get an error..." What is the error then? It **never** helps to say "I have an error". Error messages are there for a reason.

Comment: "Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Security.Claims.Claim" to "int"

Comment: See here: [How to get the current logged in user Id in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701006/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-user-id-in-asp-net-core). Or: `var userId = Int.Parse(User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Id").Value);`? I'm not sure if `c.Type == "Id"` is correct.

Comment: Maybe it helps you.
follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765214/get-user-id-in-asp-net-core-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IHttpContextAccessor` to access to `HttpContext` and get Current `UserId` like this

```cs
public int GetCurrentUserId()
{
    var claimsIdentity = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    var userDataClaim = claimsIdentity?.FindFirst("Id");//or claimsIdentity?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    var userId = userDataClaim?.Value;
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId) ? 0 : int.Parse(userId);
}
```

Or

```cs
int userId = Convert.ToInt32((User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is via `User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)`.