# ASP.net identity: How to get current IdentityUser (ApplicationUser)? Where is UserManager.FindById?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I started with the default template for ASP.net in VS2013. I want to get the current user object. This should be possible without directly accessing the database.

In the documentation, this looks very easy: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

So it should be

```
var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

But FindById is missing! Since several hours, I have been trying to use FindByIdAsync instead. But I think I get a dead lock.

```
public class UserManager : UserManager<IdentityUser>
{
    public UserManager()
        : base(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
    {
    }

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IdentityUser> GetCurrentUser()
    {
        var user = await FindByIdAsync(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        return user;
    }
}
```

The calling propery:

```
private IdentityUser_CurrentUser;
protected IdentityUser CurrentUser
{
    get
    {
        if (_CurrentUser == null)
        {                   
            var manager = new UserManager();
            var result = manager.GetCurrentUser();
            //-- STOPS HERE!!
            _CurrentUser = result.Result;
        }
        return _CurrentUser;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Either to show me where FindById is gone or how to make my code work. Or is there another way to load the IdentityUser?

**ADDED**

In the user manager, `FindById` is not found, but `this.FindById` is found. I will add the screenshots. This is not a proper solution because I do not understand, why this is happening, or can someone explain this behaviour? I attach 2 screens with intellisense open. I also want to mention, that it is not a problem of intellisense - the code does not compile if I do not add `this.`

Intellisense entering "Fi":

[image: Intellisense open with Fi].

Intellisense entering "this.Fi":

[image: Intellisense open with this.Fi]

This way, at least I am not stuck any more.

Comment: not sure this is related but `class UserManager : UserManager<IdentityUser>` always confuses me. Why not `class MyUserManager : UserManager<IdentityUser>` ?

Comment: the calling property of what class ? Have you tried your code directly from the controller with instanciation of the manager as `var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(context));`, and then use FindByIdAsync. How the hell, UserManager can know about a think such as HttpContext ???

Comment: class MyUserManager : UserManager<IdentityUser> was taken from the tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/introduction-and-overview . It has been working very well, so far.

Comment: I am not writing in MVC. This is a web forms application. Or what did you mean by "directly from the controller"? Sounds like MVC to me. The call comes in the code behind of my master page. I tried to simplify as much as I could, so the resulting code is not that beautiful...

Comment: indeed I meant mvc. But, imho, HttpContext should not be in the UserManager. Any error message, the code just `idle` ? You think to a dead lock ? At the bdd level (have you tried a sp_who2 in the bdd) ? "It has been working", when does it stop working ?

Comment: The code is just idle. It never reaches the line `_CurrentUser = result.Result;`. HttpContext is not the problem. The object is available and `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` has the correct value.

Comment: I assume that my block had something to do with this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html But marking my entire master page as async just to read the user object did not seem right to me.

Comment: I think you find the problem. I just add that the most recent ASP MVC (official) template uses `async` methods in AccountController when the method uses `await`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`FindById` is an extension method coming from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions` class. It is a part of `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` nuget package.

You should add

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

to your code to start using non-async methods.

Comment: Also, with Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 and higher, just create a new MVC project with individual accounts and you can see plenty of uses of FindById

Comment: The namespace is already included. These are my namespaces: `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web;`

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, this is an ASP.net Web Forms project, no MVC. But I think I found the solution. I will edit my question.

Comment: Thanks Rick, it helped me see how to use it properly.
            ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(applicationDbContext));
            var user = userManager.FindById<ApplicationUser>(Context.User.Identity.GetUserId());

Comment: The previous comment has some issues with child custom objects not loading for the ApplicationUser. This is a better code:
`private static ApplicationUserManager _userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var user = _userManager.FindByName<ApplicationUser, string>(userName);`

Comment: Actually, static doesn't work well, because it's not updated, you should use:
`private ApplicationUserManager _userManager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
        }`