# (MVC, Identity) How to Add ApplicationUser to Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to do a Blog project in MVC. so i created a new project in VS whit ASP.NET 4.5.1 and Individual User Accounts.

Now I'm facing exactly the same problem as mentioned in article below:

[ASP.NET MVC 5 - Identity. How to get current ApplicationUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925822/asp-mvc5-identity-how-to-get-current-applicationuser/22746384)

But mine is a bit deeper!

I don't know how to define a "ApplicationUser" in my Model. this is my Model:

```
public class Article {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    .
    .
    .
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; } //this line is the problem!
}
```

This is my very simple Controller:

```
namespace Blog.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ArticleController : Controller
    {
        DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Article> articles = db.Articles;
            return View(articles);
        }
    }
}
```

And i always get this set of errors:

```
Blog.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Blog.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

(Please note that all the 4 classes mentioned in errors above are built-in classes, i.e. they were built during creation of project.)

What should i do?

Comment: you have a typo in the article class "ApplicatinUser" instead of "ApplicationUser"

Comment: thanks, i edited the code here. but that was not the problem. it was just a typing mistake.

Comment: Annotate your key property for both `IdentityUserLogin` and `IdentityUserRole` with `[Key]`

Answer (score 0):

```
public string AuthorId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; } //this line is the problem!
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value