# Accessing logged in user Id from class - MVC 5, AutoMapper and Identity 2.0

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

So In my project have implemented interfaces and AutoMapper, and Identity 2.0 with Id as int modification form here: http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/07/13/ASPNET-Identity-20-Extending-Identity-Models-and-Using-Integer-Keys-Instead-of-Strings.aspx

Question is how to access ApplicationUserManager properties from:

```
public class EnteredByResolver : ValueResolver<ExcursionVM, int>
    {
        protected override int ResolveCore(ExcursionVM source)
        {
            return 1; // TODO - need to access loged user Id to map it to model and save
        }
    }
```

In my controller it is easy:

```
public class ManageController : Controller
{
    private ISchedule _ifc;

    public ManageController(ISchedule ifc)
    {
        this._ifc = ifc;
    }

    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
    ...
```

I could access it form interface implementation, but the same (or similar) problem.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `ClaimsPricipal.Current` I recommend to use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User` - much more reliable when used in web-application. Or when executed in a controller it'll be `HttpContext.User`.

However this will not work if this is executed outwith Http request, which is logical: no request - no logged-in user.

`ClaimsPrincpial.Current` [returns `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.current(v=vs.110).aspx) which is not always what you need, since the thread can be IIS thread and you'll get Windows user running IIS. And that is less than ideal.

Also when there is no user logged in and you try to run `ClaimsPrincipal.Current.IsInRole("admin")`, you will get an exception about "broken trust between domains" (don't remember exact wording).

Comment: how come this all became so complicated? it is just a goddamn user

Comment: @Toolkit user is part of security and authorisation. And that is complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.GetUserId();
```

From memory.

`GetUserId()` is an extension method in the Identity 2.0 library I beleive, so you need `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;` in the file

See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925822/asp-mvc5-identity-how-to-get-current-applicationuser) for more details

Comment: User.Identity.GetUserId(); did not work, but ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.GetUserId(); worked like a charm. I'll do more testing, but this is it. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: no problem, removed the other option as it wasn't right.

Comment: Beware that `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` will return you IIS user when executed before HTTP Request is present. And when user is not logged in, it can return strange results. Also always check if user `IsAuthenticated` before getting `UserId()`, otherwise you might get exception with message about "broken trust for domain". I used to have `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` all over the place, but it was causing issues, so had to back down on it.