# What is the new equivalent of accessing HttpContext.Current.User outside of controllers?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am writing a service that accesses information about the current user.

Currently I pass the User property from the controller in through a parameter into my logic class and working with the ClaimsPrincipal that way.

I know there's usually some way to access the current user globally (in previous versions using HttpContext.Current.User, for example), so what is the current equivalent in MVC 6?

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732822/accessing-logged-in-user-id-from-class-mvc-5-automapper-and-identity-2-0) explains that ClaimsPrincipal.Current is not thread safe and therefore not a useful replacement for HttpContext.Current.User

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28973242/2621693), a way to do this is with using DI to inject the HttpContextAccessor into your class, and then you can access the current user through `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User`

I won't go into the specifics of implementation as his answer covers it pretty well.

Since that question was referring to HttpContext in general, and not specifically the current user, I feel that my question is still worth leaving in place for reference.