# ASP.NET MVC 5 saving current ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, scaffolding

I'm trying to make it possible for a logged in application user the send a request, that request should be saved in the database with a RequestID, Content, UserID.

Everything works fine when I scaffold it (database is created with user_id) but it doesn't save the user id (NULL). Should the id get saved automatically because of the public ApplicationUser variable or am I missing code to make it work?

Request:

```
//Request.cs

public int RequestID { get; set; }
public string Content { get; set; }
public ApplicationUser user { get; set; }
```

Create view & Database:

[image]

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925822/asp-mvc5-identity-how-to-get-current-applicationuser) on how to get the current user,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such automatic mechanism, it can be any instance of `ApplicationUser`.

Thus, before saving the `Request` instance to the database, set the `user` explicitly:

```
request.user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```