# How to get currently logged user's email address to the View in ASP.NET c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm developing an asp.net application using c# according to mvc. In there i'm creating a user profile which can be edit or deactivate to the current logged user. In my user profile view i have a field for the email. So that i need to get current logged user's email address to that field (input tag) in View file. How to get the currently logged user's email address to a View file? And I have used Identity model.

Comment: Did you check the answers? Are you still running into issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your code, are you using the email to login or a username?
If you are using the email, then call the User.Identity.Name to get it.

If you are using a username, then use the same line to get the username then call the UserManager class to get the User object using the username and then use the email property -

```
UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Put the email in a ViewBag, ex: ViewBag.Email = user.Email.

Read that value in the view @ViewBag.Email

Comment: don't know why but in my case Findbyid is giving null. i think you are giving name over there. you should  give id over there

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla it depends on your user id, usually you have an id (GUID)

Answer (score 3):

As of MVC 5 this is how you do it based on this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925822/asp-mvc5-identity-how-to-get-current-applicationuser):

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
var email = user.Email;
```

Answer (score 0):

`User.Identity.GetUserName();` will give you current logged in user's email address.You should check default MVC template for more help.

Comment: Which namespace do you use the get `User.Identity` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really use identity model, Just call it in view:
                          @User.Identity.GetUserName()

Answer (score 0):

If you have a filed for "email" in your ApplicationUser you can access it without a query getting from claims, eg in controllers you can:

```
this.User.GetClaimValue("email")
```