# Set a foreign key ID in the AspNetUsers table by selecting the id of another table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have added a `TeamID` to the `AspNetUsers` table. There is a Teams table and every team is giving an ID. I want users to select a Team and when they are selected the `TeamID` in the `AspNetUsers` table to be updated using an action link to do this.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Select(int? id)
        {
            Team team = db.Teams.Find(id);
            if (team != null)
            {

                ViewBag.RowsAffected = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE AspNetUsers SET TeamID = {0}", team);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

This is the code I have tried but it does not work any suggestions or better ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

That query is updating the Team column for **EVERY** user in your app.

You need to first get the current user (the one actually using the app), find her Id/name to use it in a WHERE clause.

`UPDATE AspNetUsers SET TeamId = XXX where Id = YYYY`

Too much going on for a simple answer. How to get the current User id is already answered here:

[ASP.NET MVC 5 - Identity. How to get current ApplicationUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925822/asp-mvc5-identity-how-to-get-current-applicationuser)