# Get a user Asp .net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get an Application User by its Id but it is always returning null. I need it to chow its details on the edit view but because it is null, my edit view has all fields empty.

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id) {

  ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
  ApplicationUser user = db.Users.Find(id);
  return View(user);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ApplicationUser user) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
      ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
      db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");

      return View(user);
    }
```

The problem is that the "db.Users.Find(id);" is returning null. Instead of that If I do the following code everything works:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id) {

  ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

  ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
  user.Email = "test@gmail.com";
  //(...)

  return View(user);
}
```

Can you give me an idea of what can be wrong with this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update:**
Thanks for all your comments. As some of you pointed out the reason is actually very simple - I am searching for id's that don't exist on the DB. However I don't know how it is happening. When I show my ids on a table (check code below), the ids are different from the ones I can see on my table on SQL Object Explorer. How can that happen? Every other information (name and email) is right.

```
@model IEnumerable<FMS.Models.ApplicationUser>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
      <th>ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    @foreach (var user in Model) {
    <tr>
      <td>@user.Name</td>
      <td>@user.Email</td>
      <td>@user.Id</td>
      <td class="pull-right">
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = user.Id})
      </td>
    </tr>

    }

  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update 2:**
I just noticed that every time I refresh the view, the id's on the ID column are different! What can be causing this?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925822/asp-net-mvc-5-identity-how-to-get-current-applicationuser

Comment: Comment is not helping, OP does not need the current user

Comment: You have user with that id in the database? What is the code of Find method? Is Id a primary column in the table? Are you pointing to the right database?

Comment: "db.Users.Find(id)" returns null. I would suggest that either your ID field is not the primary key, or that maybe the primary key is an int and you're passing it a string. Or that the ID simply doesn't exist in your database.

Comment: ah sorry missed that it was not the current user, many apologies

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks for your reply. Actually I just noticed that the id passed does not exist on the DB but it's very strange. Please check the update above.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your reply. The ID field is the primary key and is a nvarchar(128). Actually the ID I am searching don't exist on the DB but I don't know why. Please check my update above.

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the same database each time?

Comment: You need to check if you are connecting to the correct database while listing and editing the user info. Did you try the solution suggested in the answers below?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks for your reply. The database is correct but I just noticed an odd issue. Please check "Update 2" above. Thanks.

Comment: What about database? It changes in database too? Do you have entity framework configured for database creation and populating data?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya No, on database the id's do not change.This is very strange. Yes, I have entity framework for that.

Comment: the most obvious explanation for the different IDs would be that you're looking at 2 different copies of the database

Answer (score 0):

You can write following way :

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id) {

  ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
  ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
  return View(user);
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I already tried that before and didn't work. The id passed as argument is not the correct one. I am still trying to find why.

Comment: Try this  :  string id = User.Identity.GetUserId();

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That way I can get the correct id of the logged user but I want to be able to pass that id from the list with all users so I can edit the details of a specific user id.

Answer (score -2):

You can find the user with:

```
db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.Equals(id))
```

and if it returns `null` maybe you do not have such a user

Comment: this adds nothing new to the problem