# ASP.NET MVC AspNet.Identity - How do I save the loggedin UserID to a created record?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm building a CRUD that is accessible only to logged in users and i'm trying to add extra information (userid) to the crud records.  How do I go about fetching the userId and saving it with the record?

Here is my controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CompanyName,Telephone")]Company company)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Companies.Add(company);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch (DataException /* dex */)
    {

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes.");
    }

    return View(company);
}
```

Here is my model

```
namespace ProjectX.Models
{
    public class Company
    {
        //public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: do you want to save a userID inside Company table?

Comment: Hello @Budyn Yes Yes -- i want to save UserId ( possibly also name&surname) inside Company table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it in different ways depending where you are in the code but since you are in the controller you should have an extension method like this `User.Identity.GetUserId()`; It will be string in this case but you can parse it, but be sure your table `AspNetUsers` has the id as `int` datatype. Assuming this is true you can say:

```
[HttpPost, Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CompanyName,Telephone")]Company company)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            company.Id = int.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            db.Companies.Add(company);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch (DataException /* dex */)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes.");
    }

    return View(company);
}
```

Do not forget to apply `[Authorize]` attribute.

In case you want to save more data from a user to a `Company` then you need to get the user from database and then extract user`s data needed from it and then save them in company object like below:

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(int.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
company.Username = user.Username;
//and so on...
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925822/asp-net-mvc-5-identity-how-to-get-current-applicationuser) you have more details for this:

Comment: Thanks a million Rajmond! I will definitely accept this answer!